# have mat-autocomplete not replace but add value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I know that with the `onSelectionChange()` from the mat-option of the mat-autocomplete i can do something when an option is selected but what i want is for the autocomplete to ADD the value of the mat-option to the input instead of replace its content.

Example:

- input: "hello"
- *click mat option* " world"
- input: "hello world"

How do i accomplish this without kepping tabs on the form value and stocking its previous value and putting it back (since that just seems like a bad workaround)?

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
   <textarea [matAutocomplete]="auto" [value]="hello" matInput></textarea>
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
      <mat-option [value]="world">
         world
      </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12144

Answer (score 7):

My workaround is to always prepend the option value with the current input value

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
   <textarea [matAutocomplete]="auto" [value]="hello" matInput></textarea>
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
      <mat-option [value]="hello + ' ' + world">  <<=== modified 
         world
      </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: never thought of it like that. since this is quite old i can't remember whether it is applicable to my case but i don't see why not. thanks.